# Oauth LinkedIn Authentication error (System.HttpResponse[Status=Forbidden, StatusCode=403])

Tags: oauth, salesforce, integration

I've been using Oauth Plugin for LinkedIn authentication with salesforce for a few months now without any issues; today we are seeing this error with no change to our existing code. I verified that the API keys and the scope were correct on the LinkedIn Developer site. Anyone know how to solve this issue?

ERROR:

> Failed getting a request token. HTTP Code = 403. Message: Forbidden.
>   Response Body:
>   oauth_problem=Scope%20NOT_AUTHORIZED%20%3A%20r_fullprofile%2C%20Scope%20NOT_AUTHORIZED%20%3A%20r_network%2C%20Scope%20NOT_AUTHORIZED%20%3A%20rw_groups%2C%20Scope%20NOT_AUTHORIZED%20%3A%20rw_nus%2C%20Scope%20NOT_AUTHORIZED%20%3A%20w_messages

Endpoint=https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken?scope=r_fullprofile%20r_emailaddress%20r_network%20r_contactinfo%20rw_nus%20rw_groups%20w_messages, Method=GET]

Answer (score 0):

They have made some changes to the LinkedIn API. Have a look at [Developer Program Transition Guide](https://developer.linkedin.com/support/developer-program-transition)